# OpenCV - Is there an implementation of marker based reconstruction in opencv

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, image-morphology

Morphological reconstruction by opening is similar to basic morphological opening. However in contrast, reconstruction uses two images: a “seed” image, which specifies the values that spread, and a “mask” image.

Skimage has an implementation of it here 
http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.reconstruction

Matlab has an implementation which is explained very well here.
https://www.mathworks.com/tagteam/64199_91822v00_eddins_final.pdf

There is a StackOverflow post from year 2015 linked underneath which suggested a fairly good algorithm to address this issue. It has been two years since and I was wondering if a better implementation was released for opencv or if anyone has a better solution for the same.

[Morphological Reconstruction in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104091/morphological-reconstruction-in-opencv)

I would prefer to not mix 2 libraries (opencv and skimage) and am trying to find if there is an opencv method to do morphological reconstruction. I am not looking for ready to consume code any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Hello Miki, I believe there has been a misunderstanding. Please check you  email (miki_dot_stackoverflow_at_gmail_dot_com)

Comment: Indeed. Please update the question with all the relevant information, as in your email. Sorry about the misunderstanding ;)

Comment: It is done. Apologies for the poorly phrased previous question. Still getting the hang of using stack well