# Replacement of circular spots by respective colors

Tags: python, image-processing, connected-components

My objective here is to replace the spot in `mask_image` by a color corresponding to the spot in `original_image`. What I did here is to find connected components and labeling them, but I can't figure out how to find the corresponding labeled spot and replace it.
How can i put the n circles in n objects and fill them by the corresponding intensities?
Any help would be appreciated.

For example, if spot in (2, 1) in mask image should be painted by color of corresponding spot in this image below.

mask image http://myfair.software/goethe/images/mask.jpg

[image: mask]

original image http://myfair.software/goethe/images/original.jpg
[image: original image]

```
def thresh(img):
    ret , threshold = cv2.threshold(img,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return threshold

def spot_id(img):
    seed_pt = (5, 5)
    fill_color = 0
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
    for th in range(5, 255):
        prev_mask = mask.copy()
        mask = cv2.threshold(img, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        mask = cv2.floodFill(mask, None, seed_pt, fill_color)[1]

        mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask, prev_mask)

        mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    #here I labelled them
    n_centers, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(mask)
    label_hue = np.uint8(892*labels/np.max(labels))
    blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
    labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])
    labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0

    print('There are %d bright spots in the image.'%n_centers)

    cv2.imshow("labeled_img",labeled_img)
    return mask, n_centers

image_thresh = thresh(img_greyscaled)
mask, centers = spot_id(img_greyscaled)
```

Comment: I don't see where you use contours anywhere. Or why you would want to use contours.

Comment: my mistake.. it should be spots and i corrected it now

Comment: Don't use contours. You don't need them here.

Comment: can u tell me how to replace the whole spot grid by the color of corresponding spot colors

Comment: Can’t you just overlay the second image on the first, allowing that black background becomes transparen?

Comment: i did try that in first place.. but that just gave me smaller circles with different sizes. I want same size for circles

Comment: Or how can i put the n circles in n objects and replace the corresponding circle by its  label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one very simple way of accomplishing this task. First one needs to sample the value at the center of each dot in `mask_image`. Next, one expands this color to fill the dot in that same image.

Here is some code using [PyDIP](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) (because I know it better than OpenCV, I'm an author), I'm sure something similar can be done with OpenCV alone:

```
import PyDIP as dip
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the color image shown in the question
original_image = cv2.imread('/home/cris/tmp/BxW25.png')
# Load the mask image shown in the question
mask_image = cv2.imread('/home/cris/tmp/aqf3Z.png')[:,:,0]

# Get a single colored pixel in the middle of each spot of the mask
colors = dip.EuclideanSkeleton(mask_image > 50, 'loose ends away') * original_image

# Spread that color across the full spot
# (dilation and similar operators like this one don't work with color images,
#  so we apply the operation on each channel separately)
for t in range(colors.TensorElements()):
   colors.TensorElement(t).Copy(dip.MorphologicalReconstruction(colors.TensorElement(t), mask_image))

# Save the result
cv2.imwrite('/home/cris/tmp/so.png', np.array(colors))
```

[image: output of code above]

Comment: Looks nice. But opening doesnt seem to work on color images too to enlarge the spots into same size...Size of all spots should be same.

Comment: @ChinmayAthavale: I had posted the wrong picture, I've fixed that now.

Comment: Also one doubt.. Is there any way by which i can label spots and access them so that i can find individual spot intensity and print them by label

Comment: If you're using PyDIP, you can use `dip.Label` and `dip.MeasurementTool.Measure` to get the average RGB value within each of the spots in the output image here. You could also use the output of the skeleton (the single pixel mask), find the coordinates to each set pixel (you'll get one set of coordinates for each dot), and simply read the input image at those coordinates. Simply sorting these pixel coordinates will give you a labeling.

Comment: Can u give me opencv code for this? I am unable to search similar opencv functions and cant install PyDIP coz its not on pypi

Comment: @ChinmayAthavale: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095476/is-there-any-build-in-function-can-do-skeletonization-in-opencv) is an OpenCV alternative to the `dip.EuclideanSkeleton` function. For `dip.MorphologicalReconstruction` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151348/opencv-retaining-only-marked-blobs-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294025/python-equivalent-to-matlab-funciton-imfill-for-grayscale).