# Finding thick objects on binary image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

In the context of analysing images to find zones with movement, here's what I've got as an intermediate result, using opencv with python (assume these are 100% binary):

[image: Binary image]

So my question is: is there a way to locate blobs of white with a specific "thickness" threshold ?

Here's what it could look like, roughly:

[image: Resulting image]

I've been looking for transforms and manipulations such as connected components and morphological transformations but those won't work and I can't quite figure out where to start other than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The morphological opening is ideal for this problem. It removes all the white parts thinner than a given diameter.

In OpenCV it is implemented in [`cv2.morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f) using `op=cv2.MORPH_OPEN`:

```py
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, diameter)
output = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

But note that this removes parts of objects that are thin, it doesn't leave the full object if a part of it is wide enough. That can be done using an opening by reconstruction, an erosion followed by a morphological reconstruction (also known as geodesic dilation).

OpenCV doesn't have that algorithm. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104091/morphological-reconstruction-in-opencv) gives a rough outline for how to implement it in OpenCV, but that is a very expensive algorithm, there are much more efficient ones.

There might be an implementation in Scikit-image, I haven't looked for it.

DIPlib (with Python bindings called PyDIP) (also, I'm an author) has a [dip.OpeningByReconstruction](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/morphology.html#dip-OpeningByReconstruction-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-StructuringElement-CL-dip-uint--dip-StringArray-CL). Install the Python module with `pip install diplib`.

Comment: I would also add this [webpage](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/morops.htm) containing articles for more extensive explanation regarding morphological operations. After performing an opening you can call `cv.boundingRect(img)` from openCV to locate the remaining objects.

Comment: @RobertMoga: Though I appreciate Bob’s work in putting that web site together, the page you link provide a highly incomplete view of Mathematical Morphology. That was the state more or less 50 years ago when the field was created. A lot of things have happened in 50 years.